# What is the rule about the log of small o notation?

Tags: asymptotics

Say I have the MacLaurin Series expansion of a function and get
\begin{equation}
1+2f(0)c_is_i\theta+o(\theta)
\end{equation}
and I want to take the log of this function -i.e. $\log[1+2f(0)c_is_i\theta+o(\theta)]$. How would the last term be expressed?

Comment: Use MacLaurin for log.

Comment: Are we assuming that $\theta$ is small?

Comment: @paulinho yes! Sorry should have mentioned this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $a = 2 f(0) c_i s_i$ so your expression is $1 + a \theta + o(\theta)$. We want to compare the log of this expression to $\log (1 + a \theta)$. We have

$$\log (1 + a \theta + o (\theta)) - \log (1 + a \theta) = \log (1 + o \left( \frac{\theta}{1 + a \theta} \right) )$$

and the Taylor series of the logarithm gives $\log (1 + x) = x + O(x^2)$ which gives, altogether,

$$\log (1 + a \theta + o (\theta)) = \log (1 + a \theta) + o \left( \frac{\theta}{1 + a \theta} \right).$$

(This way of writing it is agnostic about whether you want $\theta \to 0$ or $\theta \to \infty$; it works either way. If $\theta \to 0$ it simplifies to $o(\theta)$ and if $\theta \to \infty$ it simplifies to $o(1)$.)